# Create New Public Google Document Using PHP (Without any client intervention)

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-api-php-client

I would like to **create public google document** using PHP (in the background script on the server side).

It should simply create the new public document which can be accessed and edited by any one having the URL to the document.

I already looked into
https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-php
But it does not help me. First it creates a text document in the drive (Not a google type document). When  I open this created document then it open in text viewer in google drive so it can not be edited...and more ever this example need to be executed from command line on PHP and one has to enter the token return when we run from broswer. so the above example does not help much.

I am looking for some server side php script which can be called to create public google document in the back ground. (without any client intervention..) (which can be accessed and edited by any one having the URL to the document.)

I would appreciate if some one could help. I would be ready to pay for the solution too.